# Find every way to fill a 3 element list given 2 numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given 2 numbers, say 1 and 0, how do I find every possible combination that makes a 3 element list

For example, I want to input 1 and 0 and return:
(1, 1, 1)
...
(0, 0, 0)

Also, (1, 0, 1) and (1, 1, 0) are counted as different and I need to return both of these

Comment: https://devdocs.io/python~3.7/library/itertools#itertools.product

Answer (score 2):

```
itertools.product([0,1],repeat=3)
# [(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1)]
```

should give you what you want i think

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```py
from itertools import product
print([x for x in product([0, 1], repeat=3)])
```

Output:

```
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1)]
```